# Is Java case-sensitive?

Tags: java, case-sensitive

I read somewhere that Java is case-sensitive. I have been unable to confirm this. Is it? If so, why?

Answer (score 39):

> I read somewhere that Java is case-sensitive. I have been unable to confirm this.

Java source code is case sensitive, if you mean that. i.e. `Double` is not the same type as `double`, and you can have two different and separate variables `myData` and `mydata`.

> Is it? If so, why?

Case sensitivity is the norm in most programming languages and environments, because lower and upper case letters are represented differently at the lowest levels. To a computer, "a" and "A" are two completely different things, and it takes extra work to make it act as if they were the same.

Furthermore, some languages have very tricky special rules for casing, e.g. the German letter ß has no uppercase version and is typically uppercased to "SS" - so should "weiß" and "WEISS" be considered syntactially identical? Even worse is Turkish: they have two separate letters i with and without a dot, and each has its own uppercase version. So in Turkey, "IMAGE" is *not* the uppercase version of "image"! And this is not irrelevant at all, especially for Java, since you can actually use all these letters as identifiers in your Java programs if you want.

In the light of all this, it's very understandable that programming language designers would choose the simple solution of having the syntax be case sensitive.

Comment: I think case insensitive languages can easily exist without the problem you mention. If you allow identifiers / variables / constants / etc. in the program to be made up of only ASCII characters, then the problem won't exist anymore. Besides, even if you're a french programmer, you'll code in English. Your code has to be understood by as many people as possible. Yes, other special characters can (and will) exist in character-strings within your code, but that's a completely different issue. I'm not saying the switch to case-insensitivity should be made, I'm just saying it would be easy.

Comment: Indeed, HTML, CSS and SQL (and thus PL/SQL) come to mind as examples of case-insensitive languages that don't appear to implode due to `ß` (though it's an interesting point).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it is case-sensitive. It is this way because of its heritage from C. To keep the language more familiar to what people were used to "in the day", they left it as case-sensitive. There is an added advantage, since Java identifiers can be almost any [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character. You don't have to worry about whether or not an individual character can be uppercased or not.

For example, should `ß` be equivalent to `ss`?

Comment: What Unicode character is that?

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson ß
LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S
Unicode: U+00DF, UTF-8: C3 9F

Comment: An S, eh? Then why does `lowercase(U+00DF)` result in `ss`? I'm sure it'd be just `s`.

Comment: Try looking at my comment. Unicode U+00DF is not Unicode U+0053. The latter is S the former is ß. S ≠ ß

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think you understand me. Your comment makes it sound like that character is defined to lowercase to ss

Comment: @Cole"Cole9"Johnson - Well, that is the interesting thing… upper-case ß is SS, or at least it used to be (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%DF), and SS should match ss, so should ß match ss?

Answer (score 7):

Identifiers are case-sensitive because collation is a difficult, locale-dependent problem.

Comment: Unicode collation defines a preorder, which means it *also* defines case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: I stand corrected; sorry. I can't change the vote anymore, though since Joel and Jeff decided it'd be a good idea that discussions will never sway one's opinion.

Comment: Thanks, and I'd rather ignore the positive reinforcement thingie.

Answer (score 7):

Java is case-sensitive because it uses a C-style syntax.  Case sensitivity is useful because it lets you infer what a name means based on it's case.

For example, the Java standard for class names is uppercasing the first letter of each word (`Integer`, `PrintStream`, etc).  The standard for variable and method names is lowercase the first letter of the first word, and uppercasing all other first letters (`number`, `println()`, `checkError()`, etc).  And the standard for constants is all uppercase with underscores (`SOME_CONSTANT`).

While you're not required to follow these rules in your code (it'll compile even if you break these rules), Java's built-in code follows them, and all major Java libraries do too.  And your code really should follow these rules too, because it helps other developers infer meaning when they see the capitalization.

Answer (score 6):

This was more a technical decision. Java is intented to be platform independent. Public Java classes are stored with the package/classname in the filesystem. In non-Windows platforms the filenames are case sensitive. It would fail over there if you didn't use an exact case to load/run the class. This need for case sensitivity is extended to other identifiers in Java (which in end yields room for other (but non-technical) advantages like naming conventions).

Answer (score 4):

Whether a programming language should be case sensitive or not tends to divide opinion amongst programmers. Regardless of the debate it's important to remember that Java is case sensitive.
It simply means that the case of the letters in your Java programs matter. For example, suppose you decide to create three variables called "endLoop", "Endloop", and "EnDlOoP". Even though in English we see the variable names as saying the same thing, Java does not. It will treat them all differently.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Java is case-sensitive because most programming languages are!

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty poor explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The Java compiler and interpreter are case-sensitive, so you must capitalize consistently.

HelloWorldApp is not the same as Helloworldapp.

This case sensitivity reflects Java’s heritage as an outgrowth of C and C++.