# Are user defined symbols case sensitive in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is java case sensitive ? If so Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459/is-java-case-sensitive-if-so-why)

In Java, are user defined symbols case sensitive?

Comment: Doing exam ? of course it's true

Comment: You don't have access to google? right?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is **case-sensitive** in Java.

Comment: I don't know what to write in answer apart from this :-\

Comment: "Everything" is a bit too strong. For instance, depending on the filesystem, the process of class loading (ie, opening a jar file) could be case insensitive -- actually, most FS operations can be case insensitive.

Comment: @BrunoReis. And can you give a working example for that?? I don't think that really happens.

Comment: `new File("File.txt").exists();`, try it with a file called "file.txt" on Windows with NTFS and then on Linux with EXT4.

Comment: Or, `new File("File.txt").createNewFile(); new File("file.txt").exists()`, will return `true` on Windows on NTFS and `false` on Linux on EXT4.

Comment: @BrunoReis. Ok. So it is platform dependent. How come? Never used Linux though..

Comment: This is how things are: Java is platform dependent. That's why I say the statement "Everything is case-sensitive in Java" is incorrect.

Comment: @BrunoReis. Aww!. Till now I have heard Java is Platform Independent.. Looks like Several Books needs to be improved..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18013/discussion-between-bruno-reis-and-rohit-jain)