# What should I change to make this file compile?

Tags: java, arrays, file, compilation, symbols

I am in a programming class and this program is part of my homework. This file analyzes data from a file called "Names.txt" and then prints the information. I'm getting compilation errors and I want to know what I need to change or add to make it compile successfully.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class NameApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        String selection, nameIn, nameIn2;
        Name name, name2;
        int decade;
        String first = "1", second = "2", third = "3", fourth = "4", fifth = "5", sixth = "6", seventh = "7", eighth = "8", ninth = "9", tenth = "10";
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the character corresponding to your selection:");
            System.out.println("a - Print histogram for a name");
            System.out.println("b - Compare two names in a decade");
            System.out.println("c - Print top ten names for a decade");
            System.out.println("d - Quit (display file anomalies)");
            selection = stdin.next();
            System.out.println("your selection: " + selection);
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn = stdin.next();
                name = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Histogram for name, " + name.getName());
            }
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn = stdin.next();
                name = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Enter a name: ");
                nameIn2 = stdin.next();
                name2 = nameIn.findName();
                System.out.println("Enter number corresponding to your decade:");
                System.out.println("1 - 1900-1909");
                System.out.println("2 - 1910-1919");
                System.out.println("1 - 1920-1929");
                System.out.println("1 - 1930-1939");
                System.out.println("1 - 1940-1949");
                System.out.println("1 - 1950-1959");
                System.out.println("1 - 1960-1969");
                System.out.println("1 - 1970-1979");
                System.out.println("1 - 1980-1989");
                System.out.println("1 - 1990-1999");
                System.out.println("1 - 2000-2005");
                System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
                decade = stdin.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Data for " + name.getName());
                System.out.println(name.getHistoLine(decade));
                System.out.println("Date for " + name2.getName());
                System.out.println(name2.getHistoLine(decade));
            }
            if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                System.out.println("Enter number corresponding to your decade:");
                System.out.println("1 - 1900-1909");
                System.out.println("2 - 1910-1919");
                System.out.println("1 - 1920-1929");
                System.out.println("1 - 1930-1939");
                System.out.println("1 - 1940-1949");
                System.out.println("1 - 1950-1959");
                System.out.println("1 - 1960-1969");
                System.out.println("1 - 1970-1979");
                System.out.println("1 - 1980-1989");
                System.out.println("1 - 1990-1999");
                System.out.println("1 - 2000-2005");
                System.out.println("Enter a decade: ");
                decade = stdin.nextInt();
                System.out.println("Ten most popular names (male and female) during the decade 1990-1999 were: ");
                System.out.println(first.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(second.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(third.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(fourth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(fifth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(sixth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(seventh.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(eighth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(ninth.findRank(decade));
                System.out.println(tenth.findRank(decade));
            }
            if (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("a") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("b") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("C") || !selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
                ;
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
            }
        }
        while (!selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d"));
        if (selection.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        }
    }




    public Static Name findName() {
        String fileName = "Names.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + inputStream);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String line;
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] nameLine = line.split(" ");
            String babyName = nameLine[0];
            int[] popularity;
            for (int k = 0; k < nameLine.length; k++) {
                popularity[k] = Integer.parseInt(nameLine[k + 1]);
            }
            if (this.equalsIgnoreCase(babyName)) {
                Name name = new Name(babyName, popularity);
            } else {
                System.out.print("Sorry that name was not found");
            }
        }
        return name;
    }

    public Static String findRank(int decade) {
        String fileName = "Names.txt";
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file" + inputStream);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        String top = "";
        String line;
        while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            line = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] nameLine = line.split(" ");
            String babyName = nameLine[0];
            int[] popularity;
            for (int k = 0; k < nameLine.length; k++) {
                popularity[k] = Integer.parseInt(nameLine[k + 1]);
            }
            if (popularity[decade - 1] == Integer.parseInt(this)) {
                top = top + babyName + "(" + this + ")" + "        ";
            }
            return top;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the compilation errors

```
NameApp.java:126: ';' expected
    public Static Name findName()
                      ^
NameApp.java:126: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Static Name findName()
                       ^
NameApp.java:161: ';' expected
    public Static String findRank(int decade)
                        ^
NameApp.java:161: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Static String findRank(int decade)
                         ^
4 errors
```

Comment: `String` class doesn't have those methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how should i address the helper methods then?

Comment: Read a tutorial on java methods. You can instantiate an instance of your class or make your methods static.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so i made both methods static and now its giving my this:
i posted the new problem above

Comment: You have to understand this. I'm not going to give you the answer. Read the introduction tutorials from Oracle. to get you started, here's a link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity could be your issue. Check out Stack Overflow question *[Is Java case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459)*.

I would suggest altering the case of `static`:

```
public static Name findName()
```

A lot of your work seems wrong in this. For example, declarations of your strings.

Answer (score 0):

There are a *lot* of problems here. I **strongly** encourage you to revisit tutorials and sit down with either a tutor or [TA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaching_assistant) to hammer out the core syntax understandings.

- `static` is a keyword. It is case-sensitive. You must change all capitalized forms of `static` to lower case.
- From what you have of your code, there isn't any class called `Name`. That's going to pose a huge problem.
- `nameIn` is a `String`. It will *not* have a method called `findName`.
- `int[] popularity` doesn't have any size defined to it. You will be attempting to dereference null when you go to add things to this array. Declare its size appropriately by `new int[nameLine.length]`.
- These lines give out false information; I presume you meant to change them to a natural numerical ordering instead of having 1 all the way down?

  ```
  System.out.println("1 - 1900-1909");
  System.out.println("2 - 1910-1919");
  System.out.println("1 - 1920-1929");
  System.out.println("1 - 1930-1939");
  System.out.println("1 - 1940-1949");
  System.out.println("1 - 1950-1959");
  System.out.println("1 - 1960-1969");
  System.out.println("1 - 1970-1979");
  System.out.println("1 - 1980-1989");
  System.out.println("1 - 1990-1999");
  System.out.println("1 - 2000-2005");
  ```
- `first`, `second`, `...`, `tenth` are all of type `String`. They do *not* have a method `findRank`.

I'm sure there's more, but I'm going to stop here. Once you get *those* sorted out, you'll likely be in prime position to fix the *rest*.