# IsLetterOrDigit Error

Tags: java

I'm working on this java program and I keep getting error  from the IsLetterOrDigit method invocation, it's confusing me as I've used isLetter() already in the program and I didn't get any error from that one, somebody help me please.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class A11{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("A1.output"));
        List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("IF", "ELSE", "WRITE", "READ", "RETURN", "BEGIN", "END", "MAIN", "INT", "REAL");
        List<String> l = new LinkedList<String>();
        String line, word;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(line, " ;)*,(");
            while(tk.hasMoreTokens()){
                word = tk.nextToken();
                if(!keywords.contains(word)){
                    if(Character.isLetter(word.charAt(0) )){
                        for(int i=0; i<word.length(); ++i){
                            if(Character.IsLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(i))){//Error here
                                System.out.println(word);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, if you're asking about an error, it's a good idea to tell us what the error actually is.  It makes it much easier for the good people who want to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Remember Java is [*case*](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/casesensitive.htm)-[sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128518/2670792):

```
IsLetterOrDigit(...)
```

must be

```
isLetterOrDigit(...)
```

Comment: *"Java is case-sensitive"* - That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
Character.IsLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(i))
```

to

```
  Character.isLetterOrDigit(word.charAt(i))
```