# Cannot find symbol in Java (Scanner)

Tags: java, compilation, symbols

I'm totally new in Java and I have a hard time learning the basics. For class I have to write a simple BMI calculator but somehow I'm not able to compile my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BMI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int weight;
        int height;
        double bmi;

        System.out.println("Enter weight in kg: ");
        weight = sc.NextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter height in cm: ");
        height = sc.NextInt;

        bmi = weight / height*height;

        System.out.println("Your BMI: " + bmi);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error message:

```
Unknown:~ Philipp$ javac BMI.java
BMI.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        weight = sc.NextInt();
                   ^
  symbol:   method NextInt()
  location: variable sc of type Scanner
BMI.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        height = sc.NextInt;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable NextInt
  location: variable sc of type Scanner
2 errors
Unknown:~ Philipp$
```

I know that the "Cannot find symbol error" is often triggered by misspelling but I can't find any mistake. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Java is case sensitive. weight = sc.nextInt(); Don't you use an IDE? Just do a Control+Space that will help you.

Comment: Java is case sensitive (`nextInt()` not `NextInt()`)

Comment: Thanks for the qick reply! I use eclipse but this causes only more problems... when I change to nextInt I still get the same error for heigth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is case sensitive.

```
weight = sc.nextInt();
```

not

```
weight = sc.NextInt();
```

Comment: That's what I had before, but causes the same error for height.

Comment: @Philipp:- If you check then for `height` you have `height = sc.NextInt;` which should be `height = sc.nextInt();`

Comment: Unknown:~ Philipp$ javac BMI.java
BMI.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
  height = sc.nextInt;
             ^
  symbol:   variable nextInt
  location: variable sc of type Scanner
1 error

Comment: @Philipp:- You are missing the paranthesis...`height = sc.nextInt;`. It should be `height = sc.nextInt();`

Answer (score 1):

`weight = sc.NextInt();` should be `weight = sc.nextInt();`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459/is-java-case-sensitive) for more info on case sensitive nature of Java.