# JAVA Error Debugging.

Tags: java, debugging

I am  brand new to the Stack Communiity and trying to learn to JAVA. Here is the first line of code I have written below. I am getting errors on the output when I compile. See errors below the code.

```
 Class FirstExample 
{ 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
               {  
        System.out.println("Hello World, I love you!");
               } 

}
```

---

```
FirstExample.java:1: error: class, interface, or enum expected
Class FirstExample
^
FirstExample.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                public static void main(String[] args)
                              ^
FirstExample.java:6: error: class, interface, or enum expected
               }
               ^
3 errors
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `class`, not `Class`

Comment: Error in the first word: `class, interface, or enum expected`. `class`, [with a lowercase c.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459/is-java-case-sensitive)

Comment: Ah..got it...just got the resulting class file. Thank you.  Also, do you know why this one typo returns 3 errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the class with lowercase, like:

```
class FirstExample 
{ 
        public static void main(String[] args) 
               {  
        System.out.println("Hello World, I love you!");
               } 

}
```

You can check some tutorials here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Java is case sensitive, you should change from `Class` to `class` i.e., `class FirstExample` i.e., change it as shown below:

```
   class FirstExample { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {  
               System.out.println("Hello World, I love you!");
        } 
    }
```