# Java toUppercase() method is undefined for type String

Tags: java

So I am fairly new at java and working my way through the exercises at coding bat, but I've stumbled on an error that I can't seem to solve. My code is:

```
public String endUp(String str) {
  int l = str.length();
  if (l < 4) {
    str = str.toUppercase();
    return str;
  }else{
    String strup = str.substring(l-3);
    strup = strup.toUppercase();
    return (str.substring(0,l-3) + strup);
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Compile problems:
Error:  str = str.toUppercase();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
The method toUppercase() is undefined for the type String
```

After doing some research, it looks like this problem mostly happens when people create a custom class (I don't know anything about java classes yet) and don't import the method into it, but I didn't make any class (I think). What did I do wrong?

- Thanks for the replies, it's very easy to miss that the C is supposed to be capitalized...

Comment: Try toUpperCase() instead. Notice the upper case C ;)

Comment: This could be a [`case-sensitive`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459/is-java-case-sensitive) issue.

Comment: Always double check the docs and read verryyy carefully. These are computers, they don't mess around. They take this stuff literally. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Good effort but try to learn the basic stuffs. I hope you haven't used IDE. Good for beginners really... Go a head... @J.Doe

Comment: Ironic that the error is due to a letter that is not upper case....

Comment: Mark's right - you made a typo. I love CodingBat but, for a beginner, I would recommend copy and pasting your code into an IDE such as Intellij. This would have immediately highlighted your error and saved you hassle and frustration.

Comment: Yay. 4 answers posted after a comment that all state the same!

Comment: @ayahuasca It may look good to use IDE for begineers but actually its not as far I have experienced.

Answer (score 2):

correct your method name.

```
str.toUpperCase();
```

Java is Case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Java ain't VBA you know. The language is *case-sensitive* (like C and C++).

You need to write `toUpperCase()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String endUp(String str) {
  int l = str.length();
  if (l < 4) {
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    return str;
  }else{
    String strup = str.substring(l-3);
    strup = strup.toUpperCase();
    return (str.substring(0,l-3) + strup);
  }
}
```

The correct syntax is `toUpperCase()`
Refer to the API
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled like toUppercase() but the actual name of method is `toUpperCase()`
And the below line works
`"myString".toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 0):

You have made a case-sensitive error. You have to do it like this `str.toUpperCase()`

```
public String endUp(String str) {
        int l = str.length();
        if (l < 4) {
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            return str;
        }else{
            String strup = str.substring(l-3);
            strup = strup.toUpperCase();
            return (str.substring(0,l-3) + strup);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.It should be .toUpperCase();

```
public class Ex {

    public String endUp(String str) {
        int l = str.length();

        if (l < 4) {
            str = str.toUpperCase();
            return str;
        }else{
            String strup = str.substring(l-3);
            strup = strup.toUpperCase();
            return (str.substring(0,l-3) + strup);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        Ex ex1=new Ex();
        System.out.println("output : " +ex1.endUp ("musni"));


    }

}
```