# Define an exception called "NO Match Exception" that is thrown when a string is not equal to "India"

Tags: java, exception

In the problem I have to check whether a string is equal to "India" or not. If they are not equal then I have to throw an exception "No Match Exception"

I am creating a class nomatchexception and from constructor I am passing a string "America". Then I am checking whether it equals to "India" or not. If both are equal then printing "Matched" otherwise throwing the exception using throw.

```
class nomatchexception {    
    String s;

    nomatchexception(String s) {
        this.s = s;

        if (s.equals("India")) {
            System.out.print("Matched!\n");
        } else {
            throw new NoMatchException("Not Matched!\n");
        }
    }
}

class nomatchex {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        nomatchexception v = new nomatchexception("America");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
nomatchex.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                        throw new NoMatchException("Not Matched!\n");
                                  ^
  symbol:   class NoMatchException
  location: class nomatchexception
1 error
```

Comment: Java is case sensitive, so `NoMatchException` and `nomatchexception` are considered to be different classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128459/is-java-case-sensitive). Take a look on [Google Code style for class names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2.2-class-names). Does this question comes from [Define an Exception called “NoMatchException” that is thrown when a string is not equal to “India”. Write a Java Program that uses this exception.](https://myjavasourcecode.blogspot.com/p/19.html) page?

Comment: @MichałZiober I don't know. Actually this question was came in my college exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a class **nomatchexception** that raises your exception, but **NoMatchException** excepction class does not exist in your code and is not part of java.

It's required to create a class NoMatchException extending exception and with the proper overrides like:

```
class NoMatchException extends Exception {
    public NoMatchException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

And now you are able to raise your **NoMatchException** exceptions.

Also for good coding is recommended to use the proper case and naming in the classes maybe your **nomatchexception** class must be calle **IndiaAssertComparer** or similar.

Complete example:

```
class NoMatchException extends Exception {
    public NoMatchException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}

class IndiaAssertComparer {

    private String s;

    IndiaAssertComparer(String s) throws NoMatchException {
        this.s = s;

        if (s.equals("India")) {
            System.out.print("Matched!\n");
        } else {
            throw new NoMatchException("Not Matched!\n");
        }
    }
}

class NoMatcher {
    public static void main(String[] a) throws NoMatchException {
        IndiaAssertComparer v = new IndiaAssertComparer("America");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the utility of "super(message);" here in the code?

Comment: @UtsavAkashNaskar that passes the error message to the parent/super class, i.e. the `Exception` class which handles printing the error message in stack traces and so on.

Comment: @Dubas I am getting an error.  unreported exception NoMatchException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        IndiaAssertComparer v = new IndiaAssertComparer("America");
                                ^

Comment: @UtsavAkashNaskar  Sorry, I was without connection. You required to add the throws to the main method or capture the exception. The code of the example is updated with   "throws NoMatchException"

Answer (score 0):

Create a user defined exception named “NoMatchException” that is fired when the string entered by the user is not “india”.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class NoMatchException extends Exception{
    String s1;
    NoMatchException(String s2)
    {
        this.s1=s2;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
    return s1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s3;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string");
        s3=sc.nextLine();

        try {
        if(!"india".equalsIgnoreCase(s3))
        throw new NoMatchException("NoMatch 
             Exceptioncaught!!!");

        else {
            System.out.println("String matched!!!");
            }
        }

        catch(NoMatchException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: It seems the `cannot find symbol` issue is resolved.  Is there any other question related to this post?